java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'demo.coupon_seq' doesn't exist
I am attempting to develop a simple Spring Boot application for managing coupons, to create and read coupons. The application runs without issues when started.
However, upon sending a POST request via Postman, I encounter the following error in application:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'demo.coupon_seq' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]

In error it is saying demo.coupon_seq doesn't exist but I created class coupon I don't know why it is looking for coupon_seq?
Can anyone please look into this and provide solution?
Model/entity class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "coupon")
public class Coupon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String couponname;
    private int discount;
    @Column(name = "expdata")
    private String expdate;

}

Controller class :
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/coupon")
public class CouponController {

    @Autowired
    CouponRepository repository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/createCoupon")
    public Coupon addCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
        return repository.save(coupon);
    }
}

application.properties file :
spring.application.name=springcloud

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd123

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

SQL queries:
create database demo;
use demo;

create table coupon 
(
    id int auto_increment,
    couponname varchar(20),
    discount int,
    expdata varchar(10),
    primary key(id)
);

drop table coupon;

select * from coupon;

Postman :


Try using
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

instead of
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)


Thanks this resolved my issue. I am under impression that .Auto means it will automatically detect what constant I am using in MYSQL column.

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
This property updates schema according to the entities, so it'll create coupon_seq.
Else you can create it by yourself.

try this
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


As the above (first) answer is correct, you can even try adding your sequence table for your table.
let me explain: if you are using the table without its own sequence table then that table will use the globally -- hibernate sequence (a common sequence table for all table) and if there your project consists of more than 1 table then probably all table will use global sequence due to which your unique id can be created something like -- 1,4,10 etc.
so its better you use custom sequence for each table. below is the sample code -
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "coupon_seq")

else you can try this too
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "coupon_seq")

using the above custom sequence table will help to keep all the generated value in a sequence for each table.
do try this and let me know.
